# Quando se coloca vários gráficos em uma página, os graficos repetem os pontos do anterior

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directives, highcharts

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando AngularJS e Highcharts, que:

1- Recupera uma lista de objetos de um Webservice

```
function getColetorPorSala() {
        webService.getColetores($scope.device, $scope.token).success(function (data) {
            $scope.carregando = false;
            $scope.coletores = data.Coletores;
        });
        console.log("iniciou getColetorPorSala");
    };

    getColetorPorSala();
```

2- Cria um panel para cada objeto

```
 <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="coletor in coletores">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            {{coletor.Nome}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body" id="grafico-{{coletor.Codigo}}" data-ng-init="gerarGrafico(coletor.Codigo)">
                            Conteúdo bacana
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            Alguma coisa legal
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

3- Para cada objeto, recupera uma lista de valores desse WebService e monta um gráfico dentro do panel correspondente a esse objeto

```
$scope.gerarGrafico = function (idColetor) {
    sismogranAPI.getLeiturasColetor($scope.device, $scope.token, idColetor).success(function (data) {
        console.log("recuperou leituras de " + idColetor);
        $scope.carregando = false;
        montarGrafico(data, false, 'grafico-' + idColetor);
    });
    console.log("iniciou getLeituras para " + idColetor);
};
```

**Problema:**

Toda vez que eu crio um gráfico, os pontos do dado criado anteriormente se repetem no novo

[image: Graficos com dados se repetindo]

Cada grafico tem seu conjunto de dados distintos, então não faz sentido eles repetirem os pontos dos dados anteriores

Eis aqui o método de criação dos graficos

```
function montarGrafico(data, isLeituraPorData, idDiv) {
        console.log("iniciou montagenm de grafico para " + idDiv);
        var subtitulo;

        if (isLeituraPorData) {
            subtitulo = "leituras de " + dataInicialSalva + " à " + dataFinalSalva;
        } else {
            subtitulo = '150 últimas leituras';
        }

        var chartConfig = {};
        //Recuperando dados da resposta
        var dados = data.Leituras;

        //Organiza dados em hashMap organizados por grandeza
        for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
            var leitura = dados[i];
            var listaLeituras = getListaDeLeiturasNoHashMap(leitura.Sensor.Nome);
            listaLeituras.push(leitura);
        }

        //Seta as configurações do gráfico
        chartConfig.chart = {
            renderTo: idDiv,
            type: 'spline',
            zoomType: 'x',
            spacingRight: 20
        };
        chartConfig.title = {
            text: ""
        };
        chartConfig.subtitle = {
            text: ""
        };
        chartConfig.xAxis = {
            type: 'datetime',
            // maxZoom: 60 * 1000,
            title: {
                text: "Horario"
            }
        };
        chartConfig.yAxis = {
            title: {
                text: 'Valores'
            },
            showFirstLabel: true,
            plotBands: [],
            labels: {
                fontSize: '15px'
            }
        };
        chartConfig.tooltip = {
            crosshairs: [true, true],
            shared: true
        };
        chartConfig.legend = {
            enabled: true
        };

        chartConfig.series = [];

        chartConfig.plotOptions = {
            series: {
                turboThreshold: 999999999 
            }
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < leiturasHashMap.length; i++) {

            var band = { 
                chartConfig.chart = {
                from: leiturasHashMap[i].leituras[0].Minimo,
                to: leiturasHashMap[i].leituras[0].Maximo,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.30)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Faixa de ' + leiturasHashMap[i].tipo,
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            };

            chartConfig.yAxis.plotBands.push(band);

            var serie = {};
            serie.name = leiturasHashMap[i].tipo;
            serie.marker = {
                radius: 3
            };

            var dataAux = [];

            for (var j = 0; j < leiturasHashMap[i].leituras.length; j++) {
                dataAux.push([stringToDateTime(leiturasHashMap[i].leituras[j].Horario), leiturasHashMap[i].leituras[j].Valor]);
            }

            serie.data = dataAux;

            chartConfig.series.push(serie);
        }
        new Highcharts.Chart(chartConfig);
        console.log("terminou montagenm de grafico para " + idDiv);
    }
```

Como fazer com que cada grafico só mostre os pontos que lhe pertencem?

Comment: Tente no início do seu método sempre inicializar novamente as variáveis que você adiciona ao gráfico (leiturasHashMap) e também, limpar sua lista de parâmetros(data) do método antes de passar pra esse método...

Comment: Veja o que está vindo na variável "data", compare os valores em cada chamada, pois deve estar vindo repetido os valores. Faça também o que o @Dante falou, limpe as variáveis no início da função, para que a cada iteração do _repeat_, as variáveis não tenham valor.

Comment: vou tentar isso e daqui a pouco retorno com o resultado

Comment: @Dante , como voce disse, eu fui verificar as variáveis usadas no método. Descobri que dentro de getListaDeLeiturasNoHashMap() eu uso uma variável global que deveria ser local. Refatorei isso e o problema foi resolvido.

Comment: Massa! Posta a solução como sua própria resposta e da  um Up no meu comentário pra galera saber que solucionou! Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui achar o problema

O método `getListaDeLeiturasNoHashMap()` utilizava a variavel `leiturasHashMap` que era global

```
var getListaDeLeiturasNoHashMap = function (grandeza) {
    for (var i = 0; i < leiturasHashMap.length; i++) {
        var hashEntry = leiturasHashMap[i];
        if (hashEntry.tipo == grandeza) {
            return hashEntry.leituras;
        }
    }
    var lista = [];
    var newhashEntry = {
        tipo: grandeza,
        leituras: lista
    }
    leiturasHashMap.push(newhashEntry);
    return lista;
}
```

resolvi o problema criando essa mesma variavel localmente dentro do loop e mandando e a passando para o método como parâmetro dessa maneira:

```
var getListaDeLeiturasNoHashMap = function (grandeza, leiturasHashMap) {
    for (var i = 0; i < leiturasHashMap.length; i++) {
        var hashEntry = leiturasHashMap[i];
        if (hashEntry.tipo == grandeza) {
            return hashEntry.leituras;
        }
    }
    var lista = [];
    var newhashEntry = {
        tipo: grandeza,
        leituras: lista
    }
    leiturasHashMap.push(newhashEntry);
    return lista;
}
```